# Plot implicit polar equation streamlines

Tags: plotting, implicit

I'm trying to plot streamlines of Stokes solution to an sphere, the expression of streamlines is

[image]

I've seen similar questions before and this what I have tried

[image]

As you can see, a=1, U=1, but it seems not to work, any help? Thanks

Comment: Never post unsearchable pictures of equations.  Instead typeset them, using *MathJax* or at lest copyable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `ContourPlot` is what you are looking for?

Try (Thanks to
MarcoB for his answer and definition of `simpler`)

```
ContourPlot[simpler, {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 2} ,Contours -> Table[-10^-i, {i, 0, 4}],MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I need! Is there any way I can erase the streamlines inside the semicircle?

Comment: Add a constraint 'x^2+y^2>1 ' inside Contourplot.

Comment: for example `ContourPlot[…,RegionFunction->Function[{x,y},x^2+y^2>= 1]`

Comment: Oh yeah I was able to do that, I searched for it! Thanks I chose this as the answer, yet MarcoB's answer really did help.

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = 
  With[
    {r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], theta = ArcTan[x, y]},
    -1/4 (Sin[theta]^2) (1/r - 3 r + 2 r^2)
  ]
```

[image: initial expression]

```
simpler = FullSimplify[ExpandAll@expr]
```

[image: simplified expression]

```
Region[
  ImplicitRegion[simpler == 0, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 2}}],
  Axes -> False, Frame -> True,
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}
]
```

[image: region plot]

Comment: It does work, but what when I try a value of psi other than zero it says Region Embedding dimension:2. I'm new to mathematica so I really don't know what it means.